# Application using Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, tidesdk

I am learning to develop in Titanium studio and thought it would be a good idea if I take an application as sample and I came across a app available at (https://github.com/6wunderkinder/wunderlist) I did what was instructed by importing to the resource folder and when I run the application (on mobile web preview) the index.html page is empty with sidebar etc.. but nothing works .

Its a old codebase but just learning to run and see how it is written. I even tried in TideSDK since its a desktop application. But not able to Run, meaning when I try to import in tidesdk it says that this is not a titanium studio application. I scroll through the code and this is what I think 
1. tiapp.xml is not available so it is not able to import I guess. 
2. the index.html is incomplete I guess because the code for listing the task in the opening page of the application is not mentioned..

Is my assumption is correct ? If someone can help me run this project that will be a great start.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try the actual documenation from the vendor, might be a better place to start.

There is a wiki, training videos and tons of recent code samples.

http://www.appcelerator.com/developers

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the pointers, but I came from there (examples, Tutorials).In fact, its not,  how to do ? but what to do if it is not working. "Hello World sample" doesn't help in a real deal application like wunderlist. Sorry dont mistake me. Appreciate your help.